# Array reference and dereferencing

Tags: perl

For example,

```
my @array = @{$element->{$key}{'test'}}};

print @array;  # It shows an array reference

use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper @array;

# It prints $VAR1 =  [  '1'
                         2'
                     ]
```

How do I access these values and how do I deference the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
print $array[0]->[0];
print $array[0]->[1];
```

It looks like `@array` is ending up as an array that holds just one element; that one element is a reference to an array holding 1 & 2.

Comment: Why `->` twice when one with suffice?